# Postgres jsonb moving key level up

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have this jsonb field -

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "prop1",
            "opts": {
                "validate": {
                    "max_length": 10
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "prop2",
            "opts": {
                "validate": {
                    "max_length": 15
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to move "validate" level up, update each field and remove opts.validate so it looks like this -

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "prop1",
            "opts": {
            },
            "validate": {
                "max_length": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "prop2",
            "opts": {
            },
            "validate": {
                "max_length": 15
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was going to do something like this -

```
WITH RECURSIVE item AS (
SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN item ->> 'form' = 'array' THEN
            ('{properties,' || index - 1 || ',input_validation,array,input}')::TEXT[]
        ELSE ('{properties,' || index - 1 || ',input_validation,input}')::TEXT[]
      END path,
       id,
       item -> 'opts' -> 'validate' validate
FROM endpoints, jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'properties')
WITH ORDINALITY arr(item, index)
WHERE item -> 'opts' -> 'validate' IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id
)
UPDATE test_table e
SET data = jsonb_set(data, item.path, item.validate::jsonb)
FROM item
WHERE e.id = item.id;
```

I does update only 0 element, even though the select itself does return every single item

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DB fiddle with step-by-step queries](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ephu1XZ9)

Result query can be:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_object_agg(key, merged_data) as final_jsonb
FROM (
    SELECT
        data, 
        key,
        jsonb_agg((pair_element.value #- '{opts, validate}') || (pair_element.value->'opts')) as merged_data
    FROM
        endpoints,
        jsonb_each(data) pair,
        jsonb_array_elements(pair.value) AS pair_element
    GROUP BY data, key
) s
GROUP BY data
```

**DETAILS:**
**1.** Let's start with the deepest query. As [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) says:
`jsonb_each() expands the outermost JSON object into a set of key/value pairs`. This step produces key-value pairs like this:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| properties | [{"name": "prop1", "opts": {"validate": {"max_length": 10}}}, {"name": "prop2", "opts": {"validate": {"max_length": 15}}}] |

**2.** As `pair.value` is an array, we expand this array to a set of json values with the help of `jsonb_array_elements()`.

| value_element |
| --- |
| {"name": "prop1", "opts": {"validate": {"max_length": 10}}} |
| {"name": "prop2", "opts": {"validate": {"max_length": 15}}} |

**3.** Then we manipulate with the `data` column:

- `pair_element.value #- '{opts, validate}'` removes everything from the path `'{opts, validate}'`
- `pair_element.value->'opts'` retrieves `validate` information

**4.** Merge values from the previous step using `'||'` operator and aggregate jsonb-rows grouping them by `data` and `key` columns using `jsonb_agg()` function.

**5.** Build the result query: `jsonb_object_agg()` builds final json aggregating `key` and `merged_data` columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this fails with `ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar` There's other fields, I didn't, but I will be looking into this

Comment: @kotyara85 I don't understand what are you talking about. Given query works (see dbfiddle link). You didn't provide any workable script with table DDL or logs. If my answer helped, please upvote.